# Migrating project from swift3 to swift4 not able to override init

Tags: swift

I am trying to override init in my DatabaseHelper but somehow. I am getting an error `Property 'self.dateFormatter' not initialized at super.init call` I am not getting what i have done wrong here.

```
public override init() {
        super.init()  //I am getting error here
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd HHmmss";
        do {
            db = try Connection(dbPath);


            try db!.run(FormTbl.create(temporary: false, ifNotExists: true) { t in
                t.column(self.ColumnId, primaryKey:true);
                t.column(self.FileName);
                t.column(self.ReceivedDate);
                t.column(self.SentDate);
                t.column(self.Status);
                t.column(self.AwaitingStatus);
                });
            try db!.run(SettingTbl.create(temporary: false, ifNotExists:true) {t in
                t.column(self.ColumnId, primaryKey:true);
                t.column(self.SettingName, unique: true);
                t.column(self.SettingValue);
                });
            try db!.run(PhotoTbl.create(temporary: false, ifNotExists:true) {t in
                t.column(self.ColumnId, primaryKey:true);
                t.column(self.PhotoFormId);
                t.column(self.FileName);
                t.column(self.PhotoSentFileName);
                t.column(self.ReceivedDate);
                t.column(self.SentDate);
                t.column(self.Status);
                });
            try db!.run(GpsTbl.create(temporary: false, ifNotExists:true) {t in
                t.column(self.ColumnId, primaryKey: true);
                t.column(self.GpsFormId);
                t.column(self.Longitude);
                t.column(self.Latitude);
                t.column(self.Altitude);
                t.column(self.DateTime);
                });
        } catch {

        }
    }
```

NOTE: I was trying to migrate my project from swift3 to swift4.2

my full source code is here : [full class url](https://codeshare.io/G76MKk)

I am really stuck here from a day! Can any body please help me what I am doing wrong here !! Any suggestion will be a great help! Thanks in advance

Comment: Your dateFormatter isn't being initialized in your parent class. Add a `dateFormatter = DateFormatter()` and call it a day.

Comment: I am sorry but I am little new to this. Can you please elaborate  !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code doesn't even compile in Swift 3.

As `dateFormatter` is a declared but not initialized property in the class you have to initialize it before calling `super` for example

```
public override init() {
    dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    super.init()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd HHmmss"
```

and remove the exclamation mark, dateFormatter is supposed to be non-optional

```
private let dateFormatter : DateFormatter
```

---

Apart from that there are three bad practices in your code.

1. This is Swift. No trailing semicolons
2. Please conform to the naming convention, this line is highly confusing

   ```
   public var DateFormatter : DateFormatter {
   ```

   - All structs, classes and enums start with an uppercase letter
   - All variables, functions and enum cases start with a lowercase letter.
3. The creation of the shared instance is *objective-c-ish* and outdated since Swift 2

Comment: I am getting an error `Cannot call value of non-function type 'DateFormatter'`

Comment: As per suggestion if I remove parenthesis I am getting an error `'self' used in property access 'DateFormatter' before 'super.init' call` . ! And this is very old code written by someone else!! Though even I am newbie to swift! But I know some basics

Comment: Delete the horrible property `public var DateFormatter : DateFormatter {` or rename it.

Comment: That's why the uppercase/lowercase naming is so important.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that error because your `dateFormatter` variable isn't initialized in your class. You have to initialize all your variables before you finish your `init` initializer, or otherwise the compiler will complain for security reasons.

In your code, you're declaring the following:
`private let dateFormatter : DateFormatter!`

But that is just a constant that holds no value. Isn't pointing to a `DateFormatter` class. You haven't initialized it. In order to initialize it, you have to assign a `DateFormatter()` to it, for example, in that exact same line:
`private let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()`

You should be able to initialize it in your `init` method too, by adding `dateFormatter = DateFormatter()` on it, but you'll need to replace your `let` with a `var`.

Comment: I am getting the error in same line as `Cannot use instance member 'DateFormatter' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available`